# Getting the caller function name inside another function in Python?

Tags: python, debugging

If you have 2 functions like:

```
def A
def B
```

and A calls B, can you get who is calling B inside B, like:

```
def A () :
    B ()

def B () :
    this.caller.name
```

Comment: You have the source available.  Why would you need such a thing?

Comment: Because I am debugging the code in a 3rd party app's python interpreter where there is no real debugger.

Comment: Related: [How to log source file name and line number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44401529/6862601).

Comment: Marking this as the duplicate since the other has more views and upvotes on the question.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

You can use the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module to get the info you want. Its [stack](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) method returns a list of frame records.

- For **Python 2** each frame record is a list. The third element in each record is the caller name. What you want is this:

  ```
  >>> import inspect
  >>> def f():
  ...     print inspect.stack()[1][3]
  ...
  >>> def g():
  ...     f()
  ...
  >>> g()
  g
  ```

---

- For **Python 3.5+**, each frame record is a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-named-tuple) so you need to replace

  ```
  print inspect.stack()[1][3]
  ```

  with

  ```
  print(inspect.stack()[1].function)
  ```

  on the above code.

Comment: on python 3.4 at least this doesn't work, they have changed the order of the tuples. A named tuple is now being used so it's best to use inspect.stack()[1].filename

Comment: Actually, you probably want `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name`, which is independent of Python version or implementation.

Comment: @1313e: also `inspect.currentframe()` depends from Python implementation, since if you read the source code of `inspect.py`, they both use `sys._getframe()`

Comment: thanks.  also discovered that.filename can also help when .function alone is ambiguous.  for example: 

`print(inspect.stack()[1].function, inspect.stack()[1].filename)`

Comment: Can it also print the full path of the function ?

Comment: Is there an alternative method to get the same information from inside a class' `__init__`?

Answer (score 39):

There are two ways, using `sys` and `inspect` modules:

- `sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name`
- `inspect.stack()[1][3]`

The `stack()` form is less readable and is implementation dependent since it calls `sys._getframe()`, see extract from `inspect.py`:

```
def stack(context=1):
    """Return a list of records for the stack above the caller's frame."""
    return getouterframes(sys._getframe(1), context)
```

Comment: Is this sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name comparitively faster than inspect.stack()[1][3]?

Comment: Before rushing to ask, did you try to time it (using `timeit` for instance)? I think it's faster because it doesn't seem to incurr function calls and two list lookups. But things can get hidden in Python so the best is to `timeit` it. Let us know what you find.

Comment: I wanted to know why because I knew it is faster. And I don't appreciate "seem" answers.

Comment: (getframe) 0.00419473648071 :  (inspect) 29.3846197128
Here is the ratio between the two for 4000 calls.

Comment: Great finding! I presume it's using CPython and Python version 2 or 3 doesn't affect much the result. Thanks for running the benchmark.

Answer (score 17):

*Note (June 2018): today, I would probably use `inspect` module, see other answers*

`sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name` like in the example below:

```
>>> def foo():
...  global x
...  x = sys._getframe(1)
...
>>> def y(): foo()
...
>>> y()
>>> x.f_code.co_name
'y'
>>>
```

Important note: as it's obvious from the `_getframe` method name (hey, it starts with an underscore), it's not an API method one should be thoughtlessly rely on.

Comment: [sys._getframe](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) is "not guaranteed to exist in all implementations of Python" - I think this is important to note.

Answer (score 9):

This works for me! :D

```
>>> def a():
...     import sys
...     print sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name
...
>>> def b():
...     a()
...
...
>>> b()
b
>>>
```

Comment: This works great but at first it was confusing because you could have just had b() function echo it's own name. The other answers saying to use `inspect.` failed miserably because it wasn't defined. The authors forgot a dependency statement I guess.

Comment: At least for me, this was **much** faster than `inspect.stack()` by at least a x1000

Answer (score 6):

you can user the logging module and specify the %(funcName)s option in BaseConfig()

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='/tmp/test.log', 
    level=logging.DEBUG, 
    format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(funcName)s |%(message)s',
)

def A():
    logging.info('info')
```

Comment: You inadvertently say `%(filename)s option`. It should be what you have in your code example: `%(funcName)s` :)

Comment: It looks like `logging` uses the `sys._getframe()` approach under the hood, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/48e352a2410b6e962d40359939a0d43aaba5ece9/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L169) and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/48e352a2410b6e962d40359939a0d43aaba5ece9/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1611).