# How to trace the flow in a python code without look through all the source code

Tags: python-2.7, trace

I'm new Bie in Python.
I wanna trace a  python project "youtube download" which provides a bunch of functions to download youtube videos , however i only wanna know when i trigger one of the method in the project. like

```
"./youtube-dl <YOUTUBE_URL> -t"
```

it will download the youtube stream and save the title.
i just wanna know when i trigger the command what functions will be called ,
i don't want to "know/trace" other functions not related the command i triggered.

is there any debug mode option, or what kind of setting can let me do the job!

thanks you all in advance^^

Comment: Try `python -m trace -t $(which youtube-dl) <url>`

Comment: You can use introspection, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/python-how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method).