# Is there a way to limit a function to be called by a specific function?

Tags: python

Is there a way to limit a function to be called by specific function(s)?

```
def a():
    private() # okay

def b():
    private() # raises error

def private():
    print "private"
```

Comment: If you're going to do that, why don't you just put the code of `private` directly inside `a`?

Comment: Not without some terrible `inspect` gymnastics. Why do you want this? Why not just call the function where you need to call it, and not where you don't?

Comment: in my code the functions are object methods, it's more organized when they're separate, and I also might want def c() to call private().

Comment: I would imagine you could use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/python-how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method inside private() to filter out the functions that shouldn't be allowed to call it. EDIT: looks like Henry beat me to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
import inspect
def private():
    cframe = inspect.currentframe()
    func = inspect.getframeinfo(cframe.f_back).function
    if func != 'a':
        print 'not allowed from ', func
    print "private"
```