# Get current function name from inside that function using Python

Tags: python, inspect

I want to log all the names of functions where my code is going. It does not matter who is calling the function.

```
import inspect

def whoami():
    return inspect.stack()[1][3]

def foo():
    print(whoami())
```

Currently it prints `foo`. I want it to print `whoami`.

Comment: Do you want to call and execute the function, or just call the name? Because you're doing the latter now, without parentheses after `whoami` in the last line.

Comment: "currently it prints `foo`": your current sample code prints nothing, or at least it won't print `foo`. Please edit it and provide a valid example.

Comment: inspect.stack()[0][3] ?

Comment: You probably meant to do: `print(whoami())` . Further, @hero is correct, you should access `inspect.stack()[0][3]` to get the name

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You probably want [`inspect.getframeinfo(frame).function`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getframeinfo):

```
import inspect

def whoami(): 
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    return inspect.getframeinfo(frame).function

def foo():
    print(whoami())

foo()
```

prints

```
whoami
```

Comment: This worked for me: `return inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1].function`

Comment: Also using `import inspect`, while setting `frame = inspect.currentframe()` you can follow with either `print(frame.f_code.co_name)` or `return frame.f_code.co_name` which provides the current function's name.

Comment: @AndroidControl Indeed. One can also use `currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name` as is noted in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76741643/) to get the calling function's name.

Answer (score 30):

Actually, Eric's answer points the way if this is about *logging*:

> For my logging purpose i want to log all the names of functions where my code is going

You can adjust the formatter to log the [function name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes):

```
import logging               

def whoami():
    logging.info("Now I'm there")

def foo():
    logging.info("I'm here")
    whoami()
    logging.info("I'm back here again")

logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)-15s [%(levelname)s] %(funcName)s: %(message)s",
    level=logging.INFO)
foo()
```

prints

```
2015-10-16 16:29:34,227 [INFO] foo: I'm here
2015-10-16 16:29:34,227 [INFO] whoami: Now I'm there
2015-10-16 16:29:34,227 [INFO] foo: I'm back here again
```

Comment: It's better than anything else.

Answer (score 19):

> For my logging purpose i want to log all the names of functions where my code is going

Have you considered decorators?

```
import functools
def logme(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f.__name__)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


@logme
def myfunction():
    print("Doing some stuff")
```

Comment: Thanks Eric , i will try that. Is there any way to apply that decorator to all function of class

Comment: @JohnKaff: Yes, you can apply decorators to classes too. You'll want that decorator to iterate over all methods of the class object, and wrap them in this decorator.

Answer (score 11):

Call [`sys._getframe()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) to get a `frame` class instance. The `f_code.co_name` member holds the function name.

```
sys._getframe(0).f_code.co_name
```

Add a simple helper function `func_name()` to wrap the call

```
import sys

def func_name(): 
    return sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name

def func1():
    print(func_name())

func1()  # prints 'func1'
```

Answer (score 7):

This simple reusable method returns a name of the caller/parent function:

```
import inspect

def current_method_name():
    # [0] is this method's frame, [1] is the parent's frame - which we want
    return inspect.stack()[1].function  

# Example:
def whoami():
    print(current_method_name())

whoami()
```

*-> output is* `whoami`

Comment: Although this works for getting the caller's name, note that [`inspect.stack` is thought to be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407119/python-inspect-stack-is-slow). An alternative is to use `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76741643/)

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer here as it can be useful to include the class name as well as the function.

This checks for `self` and `cls` convention, to include the class name.

```python
def name_of_caller(frame=1):
    """
    Return "class.function_name" of the caller or just "function_name".
    """
    frame = sys._getframe(frame)
    fn_name = frame.f_code.co_name
    var_names = frame.f_code.co_varnames
    if var_names:
        if var_names[0] == "self":
            self_obj = frame.f_locals.get("self")
            if self_obj is not None:
                return type(self_obj).__name__ + "." + fn_name
        if var_names[0] == "cls":
            cls_obj = frame.f_locals.get("cls")
            if cls_obj is not None:
                return cls_obj.__name__ + "." + fn_name
    return fn_name
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the fastest implementation. It avoids the use of additional `inspect` methods which can be slow or unnecessary.

Implementation:

```py
from inspect import currentframe

def get_self_name() -> str:
    return currentframe().f_code.co_name

def get_caller_name() -> str:
    return currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name

def get_parent_caller_name() -> str:
    return currentframe().f_back.f_back.f_code.co_name
```

Usage:

```
def actual_function_1():
    print('In actual_function_1:', get_self_name())

def actual_function_2():
    print('In actual_function_2:', get_caller_name())

def actual_function_3() -> None:
    print('In actual_function_3:', get_parent_caller_name())

actual_function_1()
actual_function_2()
actual_function_3()
```

Output:

```
In actual_function_1: get_self_name
In actual_function_2: actual_function_2
In actual_function_3: <module>
```