# Current method and class name into logging; are these methods functionally equivalent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In the test script below based on previous answers, all techniques provide the desired result of returning an informative message to the screen and a logging file.

Besides [execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17366561/3904031) which seems to be much slower for the inspect methods, I can't see any way to choose between these alternatives. Are there any hidden pitfalls in one or the other techniques? I'll be moving the project Python 3 in the future so something most forward-compatible would be better than something which is fastest now.

- f2: 2011  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5067654/3904031
- f3: 2015  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33159791/3904031
- g:  2013  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15725912/3904031
- h:  2015  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162432/3904031

Results:

```
I am Bob, an instance of B, speaking from f1
I am Bob, an instance of B, speaking from f2
I am Bob, an instance of B, speaking from f3
I am Bob, an instance of B, speaking from f4
I am Bob, an instance of B, speaking from g
I am Bob, an instance of B, speaking from h
```

Script:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cname = self.__class__.__name__
        logfmt     = "%(levelname)s - %(message)s"
        logging.basicConfig(filename="logme.log", level=logging.DEBUG, 
                            format=logfmt, filemode='w')
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        A.__init__(self)

    def whoami(self):
        return inspect.stack()[1][3]

    def whosdaddy(self):
        return inspect.stack()[2][3]

    def who_i(self, i=None):
        if i==None: i=1
        return inspect.stack()[i][3]

    def mee(self):
        return inspect.stack()[1][3]

    def f1(self):
        msg   = ('I am {}, an instance of {}, speaking from {}'.format(self.name, self.cname, self.mee()))
        print msg
        self.logger.info(msg) 

    def f2(self):    # 2011 https://stackoverflow.com/a/5067654/3904031
        me  = inspect.stack()[0][3]
        msg   = ('I am {}, an instance of {}, speaking from {}'.format(self.name, self.cname, me))
        print msg
        self.logger.info(msg) 

    def f3(self):    # 2015 https://stackoverflow.com/a/33159791/3904031
        msg   = ('I am {}, an instance of {}, speaking from {}'.format(self.name, self.cname, self.whoami()))
        print msg
        self.logger.info(msg) 

    def f4(self):
        msg   = ('I am {}, an instance of {}, speaking from {}'.format(self.name, self.cname, self.who_i(1)))
        print msg
        self.logger.info(msg) 

    def g(self):
        me  = sys._getframe().f_code.co_name    # 2013 https://stackoverflow.com/a/15725912/3904031
        msg   = ('I am {}, an instance of {}, speaking from {}'.format(self.name, self.cname, me))
        print msg
        self.logger.info(msg) 

    def h(self):
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        me    = inspect.getframeinfo(frame).function    # 2015 https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162432/3904031
        msg   = ('I am {}, an instance of {}, speaking from {}'.format(self.name, self.cname, me))
        print msg
        self.logger.info(msg) 

import sys, inspect, logging

b = B('Bob')

for x in ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'g', 'h']:
    getattr(b, x)()
```

Answer (score 1):

This turns out to be an x/y problem. `logging` seems to have all of the functionality that I need, per  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23681578/3904031).

By using the attribute `%(funcName)s` in the format statement, the following script does everything without any need to look into the stack, including the echo to the console.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

```
I am Bob, an instance of B, speaking from  i
```

from:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.cname = self.__class__.__name__

        logformat  = '%(message)s %(funcName)s '

        logging.basicConfig(filename="logme.log", level=logging.DEBUG, 
                            format=logformat, filemode='w')

        self.logger = logging.getLogger()

        console   = logging.StreamHandler()   # no more print statements, yay!
        formatter = logging.Formatter(logformat)
        console.setFormatter(formatter)

        console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        A.__init__(self)

    def i(self):
        msg   = ('I am {x.name}, an instance of {x.cname}, speaking from '.format(x=self))
        self.logger.info(msg)

import sys, inspect, logging

b = B('Bob')

b.i()
```