# How does Python logging library get lineno and funcName efficiently?

Tags: python, python-logging

In my Python service I'm using a logging library that's built in-house and not compatible with Python's logging module. While using this library, I want to add additional info to the logs like lineno and funcName. I have been using the `inspect` library to get this info like below:

```
frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
frame_info = inspect.getframeinfo(frame)
frame_info.lineno
```

However as per discussions in [Python inspect.stack is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407119/python-inspect-stack-is-slow), these methods of using `inspect` library are somewhat expensive since they access filesystem. We notice a performance decrease in our service because of this (although not nearly as bad as when we were using `inspect.stack()[0]` earlier).

I noticed Python's native logging module is able to get funcName and lineno methods efficiently. These are exposed through LogRecord attributes: https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes.

My question is, how does Python's logging module work to achieve efficient collection of this info? I tried to dig into its source code but had a hard time finding the right spot.

Comment: Python is open source, look at the source code of the `logging` module.

Comment: Neither of those `inspect` methods should involve the filesystem - it's only the ones that return actual source code that need to do that.

Comment: @jasonharper: `inspect.getframeinfo` returns source code. It goes through `linecache`, but it also [checks if the cache needs to be invalidated](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/inspect.py#L1072-L1074), so I believe it still needs to hit the filesystem on every call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a full `inspect.getframeinfo` call. The frame object's `f_lineno` and its code object's `co_name` can be retrieved much more cheaply than going through all the work of `inspect.getframeinfo`.

```
lineno = frame.f_lineno
funcname = frame.f_code.co_name
```

In my timings, this is about 100 times faster than using `inspect.getframeinfo`.

Comment: thanks, this helped and I was able to search `f_lineno` in the python logging lib source code to see this is what they actually use too! 
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1904f0a2245f500aa85fba347b260620350efc78/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1610

Comment: using this I also noticed the performance improvement.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid slow part, i.e. loading `.py` files, get the info it like this:

```
import traceback

for frame, _lineno in traceback.walk_stack(None):
  print(frame.f_code.co_name, frame.f_lineno)
  break
```

If you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/988246a17b69e7c3077c7456bc50d04d6f153c5d/Lib/traceback.py#L327-L337) of `traceback.walk_stack` (in [Lib/traceback.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/traceback.py#L327-L337)), you can simplify it even more:

```
import sys

frame = sys._getframe().f_back
if frame is not None:
  print(frame.f_code.co_name, frame.f_lineno)
```

Use the documentation of the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module in the standard library for more information.

Comment: thanks for the answer -- as I only needed to go back one frame I didn't end up using traceback

Comment: If you use `inspect.currentframe()`, it is slow to import because `inspect` imports lots of modules. To get minimum number of imports, use `sys._getframe()` in my answer.