# Pycharm - Watch call stack

Tags: python, pycharm, callstack

I need to analize in details my python module and especially one part of my code that conducts very strangely. Is it possible in Pycharm to watch - what functions/methods have been called, from what modules (if it's a *.pyd or *.dll file - then what are their names, what functions have been called from them)?

So I need to know all about my code.

Thanks.

Comment: you looking for a call graph? a call stack is only momentary ... but if you put a breakpoint in and use debug mode you should see the call stack fine when you hit the breakpoint

Comment: If you mean "Frame" tab, there is list of functions of only my module. If function calls another, unfortunately it will not be shown in the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For incoming calls you can use [inspect.getgframeinfo](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#inspect.getframeinfo) and log evaluated introspection expression when the breakpoint is hit.

[image]

Here's relevant SO question: [Python: How to get the caller's method name in the called method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/python-how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method)

You can also have a look at Python's [profilers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html): cProfile and profile.

If you want to get a diagram of your calls after a run, you probably need to use a third party tool, such as [pycallgraph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com).

Another relevant SO question: [How can you profile a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

Comment: Andrey, thanks you. I chose cProfile, but it seems very strange, because I can't to sort my list of functions in stardard mode that is first function that was called, then second, third... At least I didn't find it.

Comment: @Dmitriy_Cert Unfortunately I don't much of an experience with cProfile, cannot assist you here.