# Is there a possibility of automatic logging in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I'm looking for some as simple as possible option to do logging in Python.

Now, I have to do things like this:

```
def log(text):
    now = datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
    _lock.acquire() # In case that I call methods in Pool
    printToFile('logging/log.log', '{} -> {}'.format(now, text))
    _lock.release()
```

And call this function before each method I want to be logged. 
I'm not looking for `decorator`.

Do you have any advices?

The log file would be a txt file with timetable of called methods during the execution.

Comment: What's wrong with the standard `logging` module?

Comment: inspect can help know caller names:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/python-how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method