# Name of the function which has been passed as a parameter

Tags: python, class

I have a class which gets a function as a parameter. I need to call a function then based on the previous function passed. Is there a way to do so?

For example, if myfunc() has been passed to the class, I need to call myfunc1() as it is the corresponding function(I already have the relationships between functions saved).

Comment: there is a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/python-how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method) getting caller method name in called method.

Comment: Can you include example code please?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the name of a function, use `__name__`, e.g.:

```
def something(func):
    print(func.__name__)

def myfunc(): pass
something(myfunc) # prints 'myfunc'
```