# Possible to know if a python module has been reloaded?

Tags: python

I'm trying to track down the cause of a bug: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3027

It seems that (for some users of numba, but not all)

```
import sys
import numba

@numba.njit
def some_func(begin1, end1, begin2, end2):
  if begin1 > begin2: return some_func(begin2, end2, begin1, end1)
  return end1 + 1 >= begin2

sys.stdout = sys.stderr
x = id(sys.stdout)
some_func(0,1,2,3)
y = id(sys.stdout)
assert x==y # Fail
```

the value of sys.stdout differs before and after the call to somefunc. I'd like to know whether this is because:

- reload(sys) was called, or
- sys.stdout was reassigned

It seems difficult to know because if reload was called, variables assigned to a module namespace survive the reload, except if they're reinitialized by the module itself:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = None
sys.zzz = 123
sys = reload(sys)
sys.stderr.write("sys.stdout = {}\n".format(sys.stdout)) # Reset to file object
sys.stderr.write("sys.zzz = {}\n".format(sys.zzz)) # Surprise success!
sys.stderr.flush()
```

Comment: Try screwing with something else in `sys` and see if that gets reset too.

Comment: `reload()` will 'copy across' the globals from the module loaded into a new module object to the existing one, thus additional globals remain.

Comment: Doh. Good idea.

Comment: Oh, and check for [`sys.setdefaultencoding`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setdefaultencoding). It's deleted from `sys` by the `site` module during interpreter startup, and reloading `sys` restores it. I believe the most common reason to reload `sys` is to restore that function.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload for the details on what `reload()` does.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. Thanks. I know what sys is doing (I explained the question with the second example) - I want to when its doing it.

Comment: @user48956: I've added a method in my answer that'll let you find out!

Comment: @user2357112 , assigning to sys.api_version was an easy was to test. In my example, it is not reset, whereas sys.stdout is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although highly frowned upon, [some Python 2 code reloads `sys` to restore the `sys.setdefaultencoding()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script). This is almost always the cause of this problem.

So you could detect that `sys` was reloaded by checking for the `setdefaultencoding` attribute:

```
if hasattr(sys, 'setdefaultencoding'):
    # sys was reloaded!
```

This would only work on Python 2. Or you could augment the [`sys.flags` struct sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.flags) with an extra field:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import sys, re

_sys_flags_fields = re.findall('(\w+)=\d', repr(sys.flags))
_sys_flags_augmented = namedtuple('flags', _sys_flags_fields + ['sys_not_reloaded'])
sys.flags = _sys_flags_augmented(*sys.flags + (1,))
```

after which you can test with:

```
if not getattr(sys.flags, 'sys_not_reloaded', 0):
```

Augmenting `sys.flags` is safer than most other `sys` manipulations, as third-party code might be relying on the documented `sys` attributes and methods to be untampered with, *and* it also works on Python 3.

You could *prevent* `sys` from being reloaded by wrapping `__builtin__.reload` / `importlib.reload` / `imp.reload`:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    import __builtin__ as targetmodule
except ImportError:
    # Python 3.4 and up
    try:
        import importlib as targetmodule
        targetmodule.reload   # NameError for older Python 3 releases
    except (ImportError, AttributeError):
        # Python 3.0 - 3.3
        import imp as targetmodule

from functools import wraps

def reload_wrapper(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(module):
        if getattr(module, '__name__', None) == 'sys':
            raise ValueError('sys should never be reloaded!')
        return f(module)
    return wrapper

targetmodule.reload = reload_wrapper(targetmodule.reload)
```

Instead of raising an exception, you could just use the [`warnings` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) or some other mechanism to record or make noise about the fact that `sys` is being reloaded; you probably want to [include the caller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/python-how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method) into such warnings.

Execute the above module as early as possible to ensure that you can catch out the code that is doing this, possibly by inserting it into the `sitecustomize` module, or by triggering it from a `.pth` file installed into the `site-packages` directory. Any line in a `.pth` file that starts with `import` is [executed as Python code by the `site.py` module at Python startup](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html), so the following contents in such a file:

```
import yourpackage.sysreload_neutraliser
```

would inject an import at Python startup time.

Comment: Thanks -- that's a pretty comprehensive solution and handy to prevent reload (why is useful).
For people who come here look simply looking to know if sys has been reload, assigning to  sys.api_version, and testing whether it reverts back is a simpler way,

Comment: @user48956: other code could still be relying on `sys.api_version` being accurate, however.

Comment: Since you can copy it’s value, assign to it, and check it again later, you can know if reload happened (assuming no one else is writing to sys.apiversion)

Comment: @user48956: Yes, I know, but code could actually *read the value and alter behaviour* based on the value. If your code has altered the value, then you broke someone else's library.

Comment: True.
Also. Didn't know you could reassign builtins. +1 for that,

Comment: @user48956: I've added another option to detect reloading, where `sys.flags` is extended.