# How to find the name of the current function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

I know it seems lame, but I'd like to have a function get access to its own name for printing error or debugging messages.  It would be easy then to have a standard way to start the printout:

```
print(__myname__,"is reporting the following..."
```

I prefer this to having to explicitly type the name each time because I often
want to cut and paste such things, and I'd like any name change to be automatic, and thus more robustly correct.

This is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method) but I want the name of the current function, not the name of its caller.

I note that the special name

```
__name__
```

in this spot is reporting the name of the package, not the name of the function.

Comment: @mypetlion this does not look like a proper duplicate, because the OP wants to find the name of the currently executed function without referring to it explicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the caller's method name in the called method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `traceback` module to extract stack information:

```
import traceback

def current_function_name():
    return traceback.extract_stack()[-2][2]    

def foo():
    print current_function_name()

>>> foo()
foo
```

Comment: It's going to be way more expensive than a string literal, though.

Comment: Since it's for debugging, I don't much care.