# Python create custom magic methods

Tags: python, customization, magic-methods

In python, if I wanted to create an object that did something when passed to a specific function, how could I do that? 
For example:

```
import logging
class  TestObject:
    def __logging__(self):
        # It would check the calling function here and return something 
        # if it was a log function call from a logging class log function call
        return 'Some text'
```

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method

Answer (score 8):

### Basic Idea

In python all the default, or inbuild dunder methods are called by specific function. For example, the `__next__` is called by `next()`, `__len__` is called by `len()`, ... etc. So when we make a custom dunder method I suggest you to make a function that can call the dunder method.

### The code

```py
# lets first make a function that will call a the logging method
# the function accepts an argument which is a class that is assumed to have a
# __logging__ method.


def logging(cls):
    return cls.__logging__()

class Cls:
    def __logging__(self):
        return "logging called"

# you can use this method by this code

cls = Cls()
print(logging(cls))  # output => logging called

# or if you don't have a function to call the dunder method
# you can use this

cls = Cls()
print(cls.__logging__())  # output => logging called
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of your code. Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on SO.