# Is there any way to distinguish if a method or a literal was passed as an argument in Python?

Tags: python

Assuming we have a method `returns_true()` which just returns `True`. Is it possible to distinguish, from inside a `foo()` method with a single argument, if `returns_true()` was an argument or a `True` Literal? (purely motivated by curiosity, not as a solution to any particular problem)

```py
def foo(obj):
    pass # ? 

def returns_true():
    return True

foo(True)
foo(returns_true())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434482/python-function-overloading)

Comment: Your title says "*a method*", but the 2nd call is _not_ passing a method, but the _return value_ of `returns_true()` which is also the same as `True`? What problem are you solving here?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz It's a different question

Comment: The answer is NO (from inside of `foo`).

Comment: It's possible, but only if you parse the file. Generally, [this wouldn't be needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), so you need to provide more details on what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Not really possible and neither should it be possible. *How* a method is called must not matter.

Comment: It may not be *advisable*, but it is *possible*, to some degree: [Python to get the variable name outside the function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121891/python-to-get-the-variable-name-outside-the-function-call) If you explain *why* you would want to do this, you might get better answers.

Comment: Yes, `returns_true()` would indeed return a plain `True` instance, and I know a way to distinguish if one was inputted or the other would be to just make `returns_true()` return something of a different type. But I was wondering if, under the assumption that in both cases we would have a `True` value, we can make a distinction

Comment: In your example, there is no distinction to make, because `foo` receives the literal `True` in both cases, unless `returns_true` returns something else different than the literal `True`. You will have to provide a clearer example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hacky solution which takes some ideas from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54122784/5189462) referenced by [Aleksi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680727/aleksi-torhamo)

```py
import inspect

def returns_true():
    return True

def foo(input):
    print (inspect.stack()[1].code_context[0].split("(", 1)[1][:-2])

foo(True)           # >>> 'True'
foo(returns_true()) # >>> 'returns_true()'
```