# How to write a cell magic that knows the input number of the cell?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Is there a way to write a cell magic that knows the input number of the cell? By "input number" I mean the `?` in the cell's `In[?]` prefix. At first glance, it seems that `IPython.core.magic.cell_magic` only knows about the cell content -- it there any way to go beyond that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This  information is provided by the `execution_count` of the current instance of the `IPython` shell, that can be obtained with `get_ipython`:

```
print(get_ipython().execution_count)
```

Comment: make sure to delete all cells that do not have any content