# Get source code of calling function in python

Tags: python

For debugging purposes I would like to get the source code of the function that has called my function.  So in the following situation:

```py
def calling_func():
    x = 123
    y = x + 1
    myfunc()

def myfunc():
    calling_source = f()
```

I would like a function `f`, such that `calling_source` becomes the string

```py
"""
x = 123
y = x + 1
myfunc()
"""
```

Does such a function exist?  I'm guessing that this might be possible with something like `sys._current_frames` and the `inspect` module.

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function ?

Comment: you need the source code programmatically as a `str` object? Why not just use a modern debugger in the text editor of your choice with break points etc? Then you can step through the call stack with the source code in front of you.

Comment: I'm voting to close for duplication, but apart from that: don't write your own debugger, that's generally a really bad idea, unless you have some crazy use case where that makes sense (or you're developing an editor / IDE, but then I wouldn't expect you here asking these questions).

Comment: I appreciate the advice to use a debugger.  I write tools for developers.  I know what I'm doing here.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I would appreciate it if you would keep commentary on Stack Overflow civil and constructive

Comment: Fair point. Question is valid regardless of your motives and background.

Comment: I disagree with closing this question.  The referred to question is about getting the source of a Python function.  I'm looking for the source of a Python frame.

Answer (score 4):

```
import sys
import inspect

def called():
    print(inspect.getsource(sys._getframe().f_back))

def caller():
    called()
    x = 123     # Some example code
    y = x + 1

caller()
```

Output:

```
def caller():
    called()
    x = 123     # Some example code
    y = x + 1
```

`inspect.getsource(object)` takes an object as parameter and returns the source code as string.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import inspect                                                          

In [2]: def calling_func(): 
   ...:     x = 123 
   ...:     y = x + 1 
   ...:     text = f() 
   ...:     print(text) 
   ...:                                                                         

In [3]: def f() -> str: 
   ...:     frame = inspect.currentframe() 
   ...:     frame = frame.f_back  # go up one in the stack 
   ...:     text = inspect.getsource(frame) 
   ...:     return text 
   ...:                                                                         

In [4]: calling_func()                                                          
def calling_func():
    x = 123
    y = x + 1
    text = f()
    print(text)
```