# How to determine the path of the Python module that imported the current one (if any)?

Tags: python, python-import

Let's suppose I have the following file hierarchy:

```
program/
  ├─ main.py
  └─ util/
       └─ settings.py
```

`main.py` has the following import:

```python
import .util.settings
```

Is there any way for code in `settings.py` to determine the path of the module that imported it (`main.py`)?

Comment: This link will give you calling method's info - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method

Comment: Ah, perfect. My search-fu was failing me. Thanks!