# Is there a way to visualize the call relationships in a set of python functions?

Tags: python, graph, project-structure

Imagine you have a folder with many python modules and each of them contains functions. I would like to visualize a graph with vertices = function names. I want to define the edges as follows: if function F1 calls F2 then the vertex of F1 is connected to F2 with a directed edge.

Minimal example with a single module:

```
# --- module.py ---

def F1():
    pass

def F2():
    F1()

def F3():
    F1()

def F4():
    F2()
```

The desired output would be a graph with vertices: `V = {F1, F2, F3, F4}` and edges `E = {F2->F1, F3->F1, F4->F2}`.

Is there a convenient library to do this? Otherwise I imagine I can covert the module to string, identify the functions and find internal calls with some regex expressions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure if it's a 100% working model but it can hopefully be of some starting point. The idea behind this is to use a decorator that is going to update a dictionary `graph` with values based on `inspect.currentframe` and `inspect.getouterframes`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2654130/12502959) (explains how to get the name of the caller) was modified slightly to get the results.

The entry point is called `'<module>'` so you can probably discard that from your graph if you only care about functions calling each other.

```
import inspect
from collections import defaultdict

graph = defaultdict(set)

def called(fun):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        cur_frame = inspect.currentframe()
        cal_frame = inspect.getouterframes(cur_frame)
        graph[cal_frame[1].function].add(fun.__name__)
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner


@called
def f1():
    pass

@called
def f2():
    f1()
    f3()

@called
def f3():
    f1()

@called
def f4():
    f2()

v = {f1, f2, f3, f4}
f2()

print(graph)
```

Output

```
{'<module>': {'f2'}, 'f2': {'f1', 'f3'}, 'f3': {'f1'}}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful. TBH I am surprised that there is no such lib.

Comment: well you can try this out, if it works you can accept this answer if there aren't any other useful ones, I will be editing this as I find better ways, there maybe 3rd party libs but I wanted to see if I can hack something of my own

Comment: I would like to avoid using decorators.

Comment: is there a reason you want to avoid using them?

Comment: Yes I use other decorators in some functions and also I do not want to manually add and remove them afterwards.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html seems like it can be of use to you, this is the first time I am seeing this library

Comment: `python -m trace -T filename.py` generates something you can parse to create a graph