# How to print the file path that uses the certain function in another file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two files.
`/a/a.py` and `/b/b.py`

In `/b/b.py`, I have a func `foo()`.
In `/a/a.py`, I imported the func `foo()`.

I want to add a line in `foo()` to print the file path which imported and used this func.
In this case, `/a/a.py`

I tried to use `print(__file__)` but it only shows the path of `/b/b.py`

Is there any package that works for this?

Comment: Modules are only imported once. If a second module `c.py` also imports, `b` will not know it happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the imported part is hard due to how importlib works, but the use part is rather simple, you can easily get the information of the caller by inspecting the stack using the inspect module, this is only possible in Cpython though.

adopted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method)

```py
import inspect

def a():
    curframe = inspect.currentframe()
    calframe = inspect.getouterframes(curframe, 2)
    print('caller name:', calframe[1][3])
    print('caller file:', calframe[1][1])

def b():
    a()

b()
```