# How to get name of function that executed code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say for example I have this fuction:

```py
def example(foo:str="bar"):
  # code
```

How do I get the name of the function (for this, "example") that executed the code, something like this:

```py
def example(foor:str="bar"):
  print(functions.get()["name"]) # prints "example"
```

I looked at the inspect modules and the examples but they didn't make sense and didn't seem to do what I wanted.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method

Comment: `inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the caller's method name in the called method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method)

Comment: @MechanicPig `inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name` worked for me! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this:

```py
def example():
    pass

a = []
a.append(example)

# What is a[0]'s name?
print(a[0].__name__)
```

As en element of the list `a`, we don't know the function's name. But by calling the `__name__` attribute, I get the associated string.