# Check if a function is called by a specific function in Python

Tags: python

I'd like to make a function behave in a certain way if it's called by a specific function.

For example:

```
def addition(a, b):
   math_operations(a, b)
  
def math_operations(a, b):
   if this function is called by addition(a, b):
      return a + b
   else:
        return a * b
```

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: You can pass in a function as an argument to another function

Comment: @Seb_ Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method

Comment: @BijoThomas yes, I think that will do, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a function as an argument and use that condition as part of your if statement.

Minimal example would be something like this:

```
def fun1(a,b):
    fun2(a,b,fun1)
    
def fun2(a,b, another_func):
    if another_func == fun1:
        print('does something')
fun1('a', 'b')
```