# How to pass doc string into flask jinja html?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, docstring

Is it ways to document my html template right from flask views like that?:

```
@app.route('/data_transcript', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data_transcript():
    """string for html template"""
    # to do some stuff
    return render_template('index.html', doc_string= """string for html template""")
```

index.html :

```
<html>
<body>
{{doc_string}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python introspection: access function name and docstring inside function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037825/python-introspection-access-function-name-and-docstring-inside-function-definit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the doc string for a function in it's `__doc__` attribute, so you can write:

```
@app.route('/data_transcript', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data_transcript():
    """string for html template"""
    # to do some stuff
    return render_template('index.html', doc_string=data_transcript.__doc__)
```