# Find which function is using a given class in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have class

```
class A:
 def __init__(self):
  print(i was used by :)

# if i call this class from the function below,
 
def my_func():
 a = A()

# I need class A to print that "i was used in: my_func() "
```

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Better yet put that print inside `my_func` as `print("my_func willl now be calling A")`. Or, just pass the function name to the constructor of A as `A("my_func")` and use it.

Comment: I mean, maybe by using various stack introspection hacks. Almost certainly, you should just require the function be provided as an argument.

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano I have no idea which function is calling my class. I need to figure out which functions does. Somewhere in my code a class is used by a function which I'm not able to find.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/900404/10217732

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## If you know the function name:

You could try something like:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, func):
        print('i was used by:', func.__name__)

def my_func(func):
    a = A(func)
my_func(my_func)
```

Output:

```
i was used by: my_func
```

This you would specify the function instance, which is the most optimal way here, then just use the `__name__` to get the name of the function.

## If you don't know the function name:

You could try the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module:

```
import inspect
class A:
    def __init__(self):
       print('i was used by:', inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name)

def my_func():
    a = A()
my_func()
```

Or try this:

```
import inspect
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        cur = inspect.currentframe()
        a = inspect.getouterframes(cur, 2)[1][3]
        print('i was used by:', a)

def my_func():
    a = A()
my_func()
```

Both output:

```
i was used by: my_func
```

Comment: Thanks but still, I have no idea which function is calling my class, I got a huge chunk of Django code in which i need to figure out from where an API request is fired. There is a class for handling that, but i have no idea from where it is used.

Comment: @cod4 Edited my answer, check the **Edit:** part, that would work

Comment: yea, that's exactly what i was looking for !

Comment: @cod4 Your welcome, added an even shorter version, feel free to check it out :)