# How to get the current test name in cocotb

Tags: python, pytest, cocotb

I am using cocotb version 1.5.2, and I would like to write an utility function to create reports/plots per test.

MWE: Implementing the `get_test_name` function so that the following test will print `my_wonderful_test`.

```py
import cocotb
@cocotb.test()
async def my_wonderful_test(dut):
  print(get_test_name(dut));

def get_test_name(dut):
  pass # how do I get the current test from here?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the caller function name inside another function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900392/getting-the-caller-function-name-inside-another-function-in-python)

Comment: It could be used to build a solution once one find a way to identify which function in the stack is the test. Maybe the decorator will give some clue.

Comment: If you are calling it the same way as in the example isn't it just 1 level up?

Comment: Yes @Tzane, the example was only to illustrate.

Comment: Check out the solution I was looking for @Tzane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the commenters, and thank you @FabienM for trying to give an answer. Thank you for @Tzane for trying to find an answer. You were close.

If you want to know a one liner answer

```py
import cocotb;
def get_test_name():
  return cocotb.regression_manager._test.name
```

but the underline prefix in `_test` maybe it will break in the future, but for since I was only concerned about version `1.5.2` this is OK for me.

Any way I implemented another method that scans the stack one level at a time and check if the frame is in a cocotb.test decorated function. This is also the method that cocotb uses to [_discover_tests](https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/blob/32f9ee98a60cd04f3aa36516346015c0eabab3a3/cocotb/regression.py#L198)

It won't work if the test is in a closure, but I never use that, and I don't know if it is even supported.

```py
import cocotb
import inspect;
import sys
@cocotb.test()
async def test_get_testname(dut):
  print('Runnign from test ', get_test_name())
def get_test_name():
  try:
    return cocotb.regression_manager._test.name
  except:
    pass
  cocotbdir = '/'.join(cocotb.__file__.split('/')[:-1])
  frame = sys._getframe();
  prev_frame = None
  while frame is not None:
    try:
      # the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule)
      # says
      #   Try to guess which module an object was defined in.
      # Implying it may fail, wrapp in a try block and everything is fine
      module = inspect.getmodule(frame.f_code)
      func_name = inspect.getframeinfo(frame).function
      if hasattr(module, func_name):
        ff = getattr(module, func_name)
        if isinstance(ff, cocotb.test):
          return func_name
    except:
      pass
    prev_frame = frame;
    frame = frame.f_back;
  # return None if fail to determine the test name
```

I don't know why my questions are so badly received

It was something simple that I preferred to engage more people

Answer (score 2):

You can use "name" attribute :

```py
import cocotb
@cocotb.test()
async def my_wonderful_test(dut):
  print(my_wonderful_test.name);
```

But not sure that exactly you want.

Comment: I want to determine the test name without passing a reference from the test itself. In order, I was expecting to have some method to get the current test, in the scope `get_test_name`.

Comment: I have found the solution I wanted, thank you for your attempt :)

Comment: Much cleaner this way! Thanks!