# Best way to override lineno in Python logger

Tags: python, logging, decorator

I have written a decorator which logs the arguments used to call a particular function or method.  As shown below, it works well except that the line number reported in the `logRecord` is the line number of the decorator rather than the line number of `func` that is being wrapped:

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect
import logging

arg_log_fmt = "{name}({arg_str})"


def log_args(logger, level=logging.DEBUG):
    """Decorator to log arguments passed to func."""
    def inner_func(func):
        line_no = inspect.getsourcelines(func)[-1]

        @wraps(func)
        def return_func(*args, **kwargs):
            arg_list = list("{!r}".format(arg) for arg in args)
            arg_list.extend("{}={!r}".format(key, val)
                            for key, val in kwargs.iteritems())
            msg = arg_log_fmt.format(name=func.__name__,
                                     arg_str=", ".join(arg_list))
            logger.log(level, msg)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return return_func

    return inner_func

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    fmt = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8.8s [%(name)s:%(lineno)4s] %(message)s"
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt))
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


    @log_args(logger)
    def foo(x, y, z):
        pass

    class Bar(object):
        @log_args(logger)
        def baz(self, a, b, c):
            pass

    foo(1, 2, z=3)
    foo(1, 2, 3)
    foo(x=1, y=2, z=3)

    bar = Bar()
    bar.baz(1, c=3, b=2)
```

This sample results in the following output

```
2015-09-07 12:42:47,779 DEBUG    [__main__:  25] foo(1, 2, z=3)
2015-09-07 12:42:47,779 DEBUG    [__main__:  25] foo(1, 2, 3)
2015-09-07 12:42:47,779 DEBUG    [__main__:  25] foo(y=2, x=1, z=3)
2015-09-07 12:42:47,779 DEBUG    [__main__:  25] baz(<__main__.Bar object at 0x1029094d0>, 1, c=3, b=2)
```

Note that the line numbers all point to the decorator.

With `inspect.getsourcelines(func)` I can get the line number I'm interested in, but an attempt to over-write `lineno` in `logger.debug` results in an error.  What is the best approach to getting the line number of the wrapped function to appear in the logging statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to the Python language starting in 3.8 have made some of the answers to this question moot.  Thanks to [@Tony S Yu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260303/tony-s-yu) for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55998744/1001165) the change that makes this more idiomatic argument-logging decorator possible:

```
from functools import wraps
import logging
import os
import sys

def log_args(logger, level=logging.DEBUG, is_method=False):
    """Decorator to log arguments passed to func."""
    def inner_func(func):

        @wraps(func)
        def return_func(*args, **kwargs):
            arg_log_fmt = "{name}({arg_str})"
            arg_list = []
            if is_method:  # get class name from arg[0]
                class_name = args[0].__class__.__name__
                arg_log_fmt = class_name + "." + arg_log_fmt
                if len(args) > 1:
                    arg_list.extend("{!r}".format(arg) for arg in args[1:])
            else:
                arg_list.extend("{!r}".format(arg) for arg in args)
            arg_list.extend("{}={!r}".format(key, val)
                            for key, val in kwargs.items())
            msg = arg_log_fmt.format(name=func.__name__,
                                     arg_str=", ".join(arg_list))
            # set stacklevel=2 to get lineno from the file defining
            # the function being wrapped, not this file.  Needs Python >= 3.8
            logger.log(level, msg, stacklevel=2)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return return_func
    return inner_func

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG, 
        format="%(levelname)-8.8s [%(name)s:%(lineno)4s] %(message)s"
    )
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    @log_args(logger)
    def foo(x, y, z):
        pass

    class Bar(object):
        @log_args(logger, is_method=True)
        def baz(self, *args, **kwargs):
            pass

    foo(1, 2, z=3)

    bar = Bar()
    bar.baz(1, c=3, b=2)
    bar.baz()
```

With this output:

```
DEBUG    [__main__:  48] foo(1, 2, z=3)
DEBUG    [__main__:  51] Bar.baz(1, c=3, b=2)
DEBUG    [__main__:  52] Bar.baz()
```

Answer (score 12):

This is an old post, but this answer might still be useful for someone else.

One problem with the existing solutions is that there are [multiple parameters providing logging context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/533077/260303), and all of these would need to be patched if you want to support arbitrary logging formatters.

It turns out that this was [raised as an issue with the Python logging library about a year ago](https://bugs.python.org/issue33165), and as a result, [the `stacklevel` keyword argument was added in Python 3.8](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/7424). With that feature, you could just modify your logging call to set the stacklevel to 2 (one level above where `logger.log` is called in your example):

```py
logger.log(level, msg, stacklevel=2)
```

Since Python 3.8 isn't out yet (at the time of this response), you can monkey-patch your logger with the [`findCaller` and `_log` methods updated in Python 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/533077/260303).

I have a logging utility library called [logquacious](https://github.com/tonysyu/logquacious), where I do the same sort of monkey-patching. You can reuse the [`patch_logger` class that I've defined in logquacious](https://github.com/tonysyu/logquacious/blob/master/logquacious/backport_configurable_stacklevel.py) and update your logging example above with:

```py
from logquacious.backport_configurable_stacklevel import patch_logger

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.__class__ = patch_logger(logger.__class__)
```

As mentioned in unutbu's answer, it might be a good idea to undo this monkey-patching outside of the scope where it's used, which is what some of the other code in that file does.

Comment: Thanks @Tony S Yu! Python 3.8 is definitely here now, and this is clearly the preferred solution.

Comment: you're my hero, this should be the most correct answer

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to subclass `Logger` to override `Logger.makeRecord`. [This is the method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1387) that raises a `KeyError` if you try to change any of the standard attributes (like `rv.lineno`) in the `LogRecord`:

```
for key in extra:
    if (key in ["message", "asctime"]) or (key in rv.__dict__):
        raise KeyError("Attempt to overwrite %r in LogRecord" % key)
    rv.__dict__[key] = extra[key]
```

By removing this precaution, we can override the lineno value by supplying an
`extra` argument to the `logger.log` call:

```
logger.log(level, msg, extra=dict(lineno=line_no))
```

---

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect
import logging

arg_log_fmt = "{name}({arg_str})"


def makeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func=None, extra=None):
    """
    A factory method which can be overridden in subclasses to create
    specialized LogRecords.
    """
    rv = logging.LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
    if extra is not None:
        rv.__dict__.update(extra)
    return rv

def log_args(logger, level=logging.DEBUG, cache=dict()):
    """Decorator to log arguments passed to func."""
    logger_class = logger.__class__
    if logger_class in cache:
        UpdateableLogger = cache[logger_class]
    else:
        cache[logger_class] = UpdateableLogger = type(
            'UpdateableLogger', (logger_class,), dict(makeRecord=makeRecord))

    def inner_func(func):
        line_no = inspect.getsourcelines(func)[-1]
        @wraps(func)
        def return_func(*args, **kwargs):
            arg_list = list("{!r}".format(arg) for arg in args)
            arg_list.extend("{}={!r}".format(key, val)
                            for key, val in kwargs.iteritems())
            msg = arg_log_fmt.format(name=func.__name__,
                                     arg_str=", ".join(arg_list))
            logger.__class__ = UpdateableLogger
            try:
                logger.log(level, msg, extra=dict(lineno=line_no))
            finally:
                logger.__class__ = logger_class
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return return_func

    return inner_func

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    fmt = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8.8s [%(name)s:%(lineno)4s] %(message)s"
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt))
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    @log_args(logger)
    def foo(x, y, z):
        pass

    class Bar(object):

        @log_args(logger)
        def baz(self, a, b, c):
            pass

    foo(1, 2, z=3)
    foo(1, 2, 3)
    foo(x=1, y=2, z=3)

    bar = Bar()
    bar.baz(1, c=3, b=2)
```

yields

```
2015-09-07 16:01:22,332 DEBUG    [__main__:  48] foo(1, 2, z=3)
2015-09-07 16:01:22,332 DEBUG    [__main__:  48] foo(1, 2, 3)
2015-09-07 16:01:22,332 DEBUG    [__main__:  48] foo(y=2, x=1, z=3)
2015-09-07 16:01:22,332 DEBUG    [__main__:  53] baz(<__main__.Bar object at 0x7f17f75b0490>, 1, c=3, b=2)
```

---

The line

```
    UpdateableLogger = type('UpdateableLogger', (type(logger),), 
                            dict(makeRecord=makeRecord))
```

creates a new class which is a subclass of `type(logger)` which overrides `makeRecord`. 
Inside `return_func`, the `logger`'s class is changed to `UpdateableLogger` so the call to `logger.log` can modify `lineno` and then the original logger class is restored.

By doing it this way -- by avoiding monkey-patching `Logger.makeRecord` -- all `logger`s behave exactly as before outside the decorated functions.

---

For comparison, the monkey-patching approach is [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/fc258ee8-694c-44c9-8369-ebf067ac913f/view-source).

Comment: The approach might work, but unfortunately, the current implementation changes the behavior for other loggers (and they will raise an exception at present due to trying to pass None to dict.update()).

Comment: @PatrickMaupin: Thanks for the correction (regarding the exception). Now fixed with `if extra is not None`.

Comment: You've still ditched some of the original behavior of that function -- shouldn't be too hard to get it back if you do something like create a special dict subclass, though.

Comment: I've modified the solution to avoid monkey-patching `logging.Logger.makeRecord`. Now all loggers will behave exactly as before outside the decorated function. Only inside the decorated function can the lineno be changed.

Comment: Y'know, I think if I needed this, I'd replace this function, except permanently --  IMO, it's incredibly unPythonic to work to thwart the programmer's intentions that way.

Comment: (sorry to keep re-doing this comment) Thanks for the input. Using IPython %timeit, I get a small (10µs penalty) with foo() decorated this way v. foo() decorated with @PatrickMaupin's singleton.

Comment: This is probably better if you are doing multithreaded stuff.  The other may be better if you need it to go faster.

Comment: @TimD: Exactly how are you using `%timeit`? And does a 10µs penalty really matter?

Comment: @unutbu I ran `%timeit foo()` with `foo` decorated both ways (90us v 100us).  This is compared to undecorated `foo()` at ~130ns.  I am concerned about performance because I have a system that can call some of these decorated functions many tens or hundreds of thousands of times,

Comment: If the undecorated function takes about 130ns and the decorated function takes about 100us, then the performance of the function has already taken a ~700x hit. Once you attempt to log, it seems you've already thrown the goal of performance out the window. Why care if it is 770x slower or just 690x slower?

Comment: I didn't clarify.  Most of the functions I'm decorating take much longer than 130 ns to run.  It makes more sense to think of the constant time added rather than a multiple.  I haven't profiled the code thoroughly to quantify the impact.  You have a good point, though.  Overall run times are 5-10 minutes, and I should not be that worried about an extra 1-10 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

As Martijn points out, things sometimes change.  However, since you're using Python 2 (the iteritems gave it away), the following code will work if you don't mind monkey-patching logging:

```
from functools import wraps
import logging

class ArgLogger(object):
    """
    Singleton class -- will only be instantiated once
    because of the monkey-patching of logger.
    """

    singleton = None

    def __new__(cls):
        self = cls.singleton
        if self is not None:
            return self
        self = cls.singleton = super(ArgLogger, cls).__new__(cls)
        self.code_location = None

        # Do the monkey patch exactly one time
        def findCaller(log_self):
            self.code_location, code_location = None, self.code_location
            if code_location is not None:
                return code_location
            return old_findCaller(log_self)
        old_findCaller = logging.Logger.findCaller
        logging.Logger.findCaller = findCaller

        return self

    def log_args(self, logger, level=logging.DEBUG):
        """Decorator to log arguments passed to func."""
        def inner_func(func):
            co = func.__code__
            code_loc = (co.co_filename, co.co_firstlineno, co.co_name)

            @wraps(func)
            def return_func(*args, **kwargs):
                arg_list = list("{!r}".format(arg) for arg in args)
                arg_list.extend("{}={!r}".format(key, val)
                                for key, val in kwargs.iteritems())
                msg = "{name}({arg_str})".format(name=func.__name__,
                                        arg_str=", ".join(arg_list))
                self.code_location = code_loc
                logger.log(level, msg)
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            return return_func

        return inner_func


log_args = ArgLogger().log_args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    fmt = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8.8s [%(name)s:%(lineno)4s] %(message)s"
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt))
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


    @log_args(logger)
    def foo(x, y, z):
        pass

    class Bar(object):
        @log_args(logger)
        def baz(self, a, b, c):
            pass

    def test_regular_log():
        logger.debug("Logging without ArgLog still works fine")

    foo(1, 2, z=3)
    foo(1, 2, 3)
    foo(x=1, y=2, z=3)

    bar = Bar()
    bar.baz(1, c=3, b=2)
    test_regular_log()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Would I have to pass `my_log_info` to logger.log? Also, I use the logger a lot in other places, so I don't want to permanently mutate it.  I'm uncomfortable with the monkey-patch from that point of view.

Comment: No, this works as written with 2.7 (try it!).  And the patch is not too horrible -- logging from other places will work as it always did, due to the fact that the original code is called if we aren't logging from here.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that does.  I need to do a bit more testing and then get your solution past a code review ;-) then I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: Cleaned it up and added a test showing regular logging not affected.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily change the line number, because the [`Logger.findCaller()` method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1231) extracts this information via introspection.

You *could* re-build the function and code objects for the wrapper function you generate, but that is very hairy indeed (see the hoops I and Veedrac jump through on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550228/can-you-patch-just-a-nested-function-with-closure-or-must-the-whole-outer-fun)) and *will* lead to problems when you have a bug, as your traceback will show the wrong source lines!

You'd be better off adding the line number, as well as your *module name* (since that can differ too) to your log output manually:

```
arg_log_fmt = "{name}({arg_str}) in {filename}:{lineno}"

# ...

codeobj = func.__code__
msg = arg_log_fmt.format(
    name=func.__name__, arg_str=", ".join(arg_list),
    filename=codeobj.co_filename, lineno=codeobj.co_firstlineno)
```

Since you always have a function here, I used some more direct introspection to get the first line number for the function, via the associated code object.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's have a look at how this exception happens in [makeRecord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.makeRecord):

```
def makeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info,
               func=None, extra=None, sinfo=None):
    """
    A factory method which can be overridden in subclasses to create
    specialized LogRecords.
    """
    rv = _logRecordFactory(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func,
                         sinfo)
    if extra is not None:
        for key in extra:
            if (key in ["message", "asctime"]) or (key in rv.__dict__):
                raise KeyError("Attempt to overwrite %r in LogRecord" % key)
            rv.__dict__[key] = extra[key]
    return rv
```

In [makeRecord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.makeRecord) function, if the key is already defined in rv, it will throw a KeyError.
One simple and elegant way is to override makeRecord function, of course. But I would rather recommend you to override record factory function, which is also the recommend method for inject your own values into a [LogRecord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord) at creation time, as shown by the following pattern:

```
old_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()
def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):
    record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
    record.custom_attribute = 0xdecafbad
    return record
logging.setLogRecordFactory(record_factory)
```

Also inspired by [methods to modify frame.f_locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650744/modify-existing-variable-in-locals-or-frame-f-locals), we can accessory the **extra** in makeRecord and use it to update and then set **extra** to **None** to escape from check.

```
old_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()
def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):    
    # get extra
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    extra = frame.f_locals['extra']
    # update
    record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
    for ii, (key, value) in enumerate(extra.items()):
        exec('record.{} = value'.format(key))
    # reset extra to None
    frame.f_locals.update(dict(extra=None))
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyFrame_LocalsToFast(
        ctypes.py_object(frame), ctypes.c_int(0))
    return record
logging.setLogRecordFactory(record_factory)
```