# How can I log messages about the process before the logger is configured?

Tags: python, logging

How can I log messages about the process before the logger is configured?

I would like to save messages about the process in a log file before the logger is configured as well as after it's configured.

The reason I want to do this is because the process of determining the log file name is complicated and I want to log the process.

Therefore, I thought of the following code in order to log about the process before the logger is set.

This code determines the log file name based on the date of the argument entered by the user. It also stores log messages in a buffer list and logs to a log file after it is set.

```py
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from logging import getLogger, DEBUG, FileHandler, Formatter

LOGGER = getLogger("test")
LOGGER.setLevel(DEBUG)

# message buffer storing messages before setting logging
MSG_BUFFER = []


def gen_log_file_name(date):
    # Determine the log file name based on date.
    # the actual process is more complicated
    log_file_name = date.strftime("%b, %Y.log")
    MSG_BUFFER.append(f"log_file_name: {log_file_name}")
    return log_file_name


def log_before_set_file():
    # Determine the log file name based on the argument, "date".
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("date")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    date_arg = args.date

    date = pd.to_datetime(date_arg, format="%Y-%m-%d")
    log_file_name = gen_log_file_name(date)

    # create file handler and set level to debug
    ch = FileHandler(log_file_name)
    ch.setLevel(DEBUG)
    # create formatter
    formatter = Formatter("%(lineno)d %(levelname)s %(message)s")
    # add formatter to ch
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add ch to logger
    LOGGER.addHandler(ch)

    # Output the msg in the buffer to the log file.
    for msg in MSG_BUFFER:
        LOGGER.info(msg)

    LOGGER.info("logfile setting finished")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_before_set_file()
```

This code works fine. However, this code can't set the diffrent log level, and the output of `%(lineno)d` by the formatter will be different from the actual source line number.

I read the [Python logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html), and I feel that there is a better way to do it using [MemoryHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.MemoryHandler) etc. Do you have any advice?

Comment: This might help with the lineno problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/32443808/5640517

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your logger with a `MemoryHandler`:

```
from logging.handlers import MemoryHandler

MEMORY_HANDLER = MemoryHandler(100)

LOGGER = getLogger("test")
LOGGER.setLevel(DEBUG)
LOGGER.addHandler(MEMORY_HANDLER)
```

The `MemoryHandler` buffers the incoming log messages, but does nothing with them yet. The argument `100` is how many messages it will keep in memory at most.

When you have your final handler ready, tell the `MemoryHandler` to flush to it, then replace the `MemoryHandler` by the final handler:

```
    MEMORY_HANDLER.setTarget(ch)
    MEMORY_HANDLER.close()  # Calls flush()
    LOGGER.removeHandler(MEMORY_HANDLER)
    LOGGER.addHandler(ch)
```

Comment: Let's say application halts for some reason. How would we flush it?

Comment: You probably need a background thread for that.