# Determine which print statement is producing a line of output in terminal

Tags: python

Is there a way to determine which print statement produces a line of output in a python terminal? The use case is a large body of code across multiple files wherein it would be difficult or time-consuming to track down the specific line resulting in a printed statement. As a result, during runtime, I can't tell where the print statements are being executed from.

Comment: use `grep` in a linux or `findstr` https://mkyong.com/linux/grep-for-windows-findstr-example/

Comment: Use a debugger?

Comment: Can't use grep or findstr because the output is a variable which is converted to a string rather than a string literal, so you'd need to know the variable name rather than the variable value (which is printed) to search it

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be `import logging` and use that rather than using `print`

Then configure it to [include line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/533077/2308683) and module names

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to tell would be to just add some indicators, whether they be line numbers or the context surrounding the print statement:

```
print('put info here and this statement was executed from line x in file x')
...
```

Comment: Sounds like the OP doesn't want to edit the file. Otherwise, they would _already know_ where the print happened