# How can i show the line in which the error occurs?

Tags: python, logging

so i followed a game building tutorial for python that is using pygame, i added some functionalties to it and it crashes after reaching a certain stage. I don't know which line is the problem so i implemented logging after reading a few tutorials about it, but i can't get the log file to show which line was the problem, i googled and the only code that actually showed it had `try` and `except`    do i need to implement both of them in the game to be able to get the specific line? i am not sure if that will be efficent to do in a game. is there any way of making the log file inlcude the lines in it? Thanks! also i am new to coding, just putting it out there.

```
#logging config
logging.basicConfig(filename="log.txt", level=logging.DEBUG,filemode="w",format="%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s",datefmt="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

#Logging
logging.debug('Debug Information')
logging.info('info Information')
logging.warning('warning Information')
logging.error('error Information')
logging.critical('critical Information')
```

Comment: Python already tells the line where the exception occured. Can you paste the error you get ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log source file name and line number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533048/how-to-log-source-file-name-and-line-number-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to override the python default error handler, in order to add a logging command:

```
import sys
import traceback

logging.basicConfig(
    filename="log.txt",
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filemode="w",
    format="%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s",
    datefmt="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
)

SYS_EXCEPT_HOOK = sys.excepthook


def _excepthook(typ, value, trace):
    """ override builtin excepthook """
    logging.error("{}\n{}\n{}".format(typ.__name__, value, ''.join(traceback.format_tb(trace))))
    SYS_EXCEPT_HOOK(typ, value, trace)

sys.excepthook = _excepthook

a = 1 / 0
```

This will log:

```
08/01/2021 10:37:38 AM:ERROR:ZeroDivisionError
division by zero
  File "/home/devone/dev/scripts/sugar2dolibarr/test.py", line 23, in <module>
    a = 1 / 0
```

**UPDATE**

Every exception thrown is handled by the `sys.excepthook` builtin method.

Here I've created a new method (`_excepthook`, but you can pick the name you want) that will process the exception instead.

But since we still want python to handle this exception after we logged it, I stored the initial `excepthook` in a variable (here: SYS_EXCEPT_HOOK but again, you pick the name), and we call it immediatly after having logged the error.

Then we replace the default sys.excepthook by the one we just make.

> The only role of the traceback lib is to reconstruct the traceback of the exception, like the default error handler does.

Comment: Thank you so much! i will probabaly need to read the traceback documention to see how this works

Comment: I updated my answer with more explanations, in case it was not very clear, you tell me if that seems clearer to you?

Comment: It definitely did, Thank you so much!